# how to call destructor only once when fork

Tags: c++, fork, raii

I wrote `MmapHandler` that provides a shared memory among processes using `mmap` and at destruction, it unmaps the shared memory. I want `munmap` to be called once by the parent process. However, this unfortunately gets called by all child processes:

`MmapHandler.h`:

```
template<typename T>
class MmapHandler{
protected:
  size_t m_size;
  T* m_ptr;
public:
  MmapHandler(size_t);
  ~MmapHandler();
}
```

`MmapHandler.cpp`:

```
template<typename T>
MmapHandler<T>::MmapHandler(size_t size): m_size(size), m_ptr(MAP_FAILED)
{
  m_ptr = static_cast<T*>(mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  if(m_ptr == MAP_FAILED){
    throw std::exception();
  }
}

template<typename T>
MmapHandler<T>::~MmapHandler()
{
  if(m_ptr != MAP_FAILED)
  {
    munmap(static_cast<void*>(m_ptr), m_size);
  }
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
int num_procs = 3;
pid_t pids[num_procs];
MmapHandler sharedMemory(4096);
for(int i=0; i<num_procs; i++)
{
  if((pids[i] = fork()) < 0){
    perror("fork");
  }
  else if (pids[i] == 0){

    // do something with sharedMemory
    // ...
    // 

    return 0;
  }
}

while(wait(NULL) > 0);
// all children done!
return 0;
```

If one of the children process exits (e.g. exception), then it destroys the sharedmemory (e.g. munmap). Is there a way I can disable this on my child processes?

I can pass an argument such that only a certain pid can unmap the shared memory, but is there a more elegant C++ way of doing this?

I thought about `=delete` on destructor for child processes only using macros but this obviously won't work...

I also thought about creating a wrapper `MmapHandler` class that would `=delete` the destructor, and all the other `MmapHandler` will be moved to the wrapper handler, but I'm not sure if this'll work.

Comment: When you fork a process, the parent and child receive a different return code.   Based on that, they can do different things.    In your case, it will also be necessary to create the `MmapHandler` differently (currently, it is created with automatic storage duration, so both parent and child will destruct it.  Instead, create it dynamically, which means you can control which process destroys it).

Comment: But they do both have to `munmap()` the memory. It's correct for both to call the destructor or you leak resources. *"The child process and the parent process run in separate memory spaces. At the time of fork() both memory spaces have the same content.  Memory writes,  file  mappings (mmap(2)), and unmappings (munmap(2)) performed by one of the processes do not affect the other."* You have a X/Y problem.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I'm using `MAP_SHARED`, so if one of them unmaps it, I believe all processes lose access.

Comment: No. MAP_SHARED only means they share the underlying physical pages. When you write to the memory and call `msync()` then the other process will see the changes.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow hmmm, so I'm using `MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS`, so it's not backed by any file, meaning `msync` is not necessary. So if I were to `munmap` in one of my child processes, it simply unmaps the child virtual page to physical page mapping, and the mapping to the physical page in other child processes still remains? I guess my question is: does the physical page get released when `munmap` is called by one of the child processes?

Comment: No, the physical pages are reference counted.

Answer (score 1):

Why pass an argument, with anyone's pid, somewhere? There's no need to do that.

```
m_ptr = static_cast<T*>(mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
```

Here's where you're `mmap`ing the memory segment. How about calling `getpid()` right here. This gives you your own pid, that you can save somewhere.

```
T* m_ptr;
```

It seems logical that the `pid_t` would also be saved, right next to the `m_ptr`.

```
munmap(static_cast<void*>(m_ptr), m_size);
```

And this is where the shared memory segment is getting unmapped. It should now be obvious that calling `getpid()` here lets you check if it's the same pid that mapped it, and unmap it only in that case, and do nothing if it's some other process.

Now, nothing outside of this class needs to do anything, and *The Right Thing Will Happen*.

Answer (score 0):

Store a reference counter in your shared memory; and have the last process free the memory. The counter must be syncronized between processes, so an interprocess counting semaphore may serve the trick.

Iff you can confirm that the grand parent is the last man standing or want to grant it the privilege of ownership of shared memory, you can store the PID of that process inside the constructor, and decide to delete in destructor - based on a comparison to current PID.

Using `fork` after using C++ specific code is often not considered good practice though. `system`, `spawn` or other utilities such as **boost.interprocess** might give better results.

Regards,
FM.